# allowsInlinePlayback true doesn't work in webvuew iOS app

Tags: webview, wkwebview

I have an issue with my iOS application. I put webConfiguration.allowsInlinePlayback true and app still open video tag in Live BroadCast mode on Iphone. Also I pus JS attribute and HTML attribute playsinline but it still open it fullscreen. How to resolve this issue?

My tryings I described above